# Advancements gained from knowledge in prime numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, applications

If we figured out a way to find the prime factors of *any* number (the amount of time it takes to figure it out is proportionate to the number of digits) or if the number is prime, what could we use with this information? Let's assume RSA has already been broken and "everyone" knows (meaning you can look it up) how to do it. Most other questions have to do with current benefits, but I'm asking how we could use this information to benefit us.

Comment: The Chess professional, realizing that the Chess amateur is about to destroy all of the artistic significance of the great Chess games of the past, murders the Chess amateur and burns the Chess analysis.

Comment: We would just know much more factorizations and prime numbers and RSA would be useless. That's it.